# Orchard: Full Source or Not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, orchardcms

We're going to be using Orchard as a base for a particular client. We're a C# shop running VS2K10. We'll throw it in our version control system as per the norm for our projects.

That said, we'll be creating custom modules based on the needs of our clients. What approach does everyone here recommend?

1. Get full source from CodePlex and check that in
2. Download just the Orchard web code (similar to Web Platform Installer)

Problem with #1 is that the code base is rather large, but it will allow us to debug the site locally when developing.

What are the caveats with #2? Lack of debugging?

I'm curious what everyone's approach would be for this. I'm inclined to go with #1, get the full source, throw it in SVN, and build off of that.

Thoughts?

Comment: please ask this as a specific technical discussion not a what are your thoughts on this.

Comment: Well, this is a specific technical discussion regarding the merits of full source Orchard vs. just web. How would you like this reworded?

Comment: what are your specific concerns, as of right now there is no definitive answer to your question as you are asking for what peoples approaches would be, as there is no 'correct answer' to that question it doesn't really fit.

Comment: I guess the real question comes down to this: Best approach to developing a site in Orchard that will rely on custom modules. Using the full source or not? Otherwise, where would this go? I've asked open ended questions in the past without issue, so if this is a problem, I'd like to know where to place this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are going to develop modules using Visual Studio, just use the full source code. Disk space is cheap.
Caveats with #2 are that it's immensely less comfortable. Why bother?

Comment: Hi Bertrand, thanks for the information! I've been playing with a few of your modules. Thanks for your contributions!

Comment: Bertrand is also the Program Manager for Orchard, so we all owe him a lot of thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I use the full source version, but I only check the modules and themes that I'm working on into source control.

I did originally use just the web code, but found myself running into lots of little problems that were much easier to track down when using the full source.

I found that only source controlling the stuff I was working on made updating to later versions of Orchard much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no software engineer, but here is what I would do :

- Get the source code.
- Add it in your VS solution and source control.
- Do NOT reference the project(s).
- Add a post-build event on that project to copy the dll and the symbols (for debug) in the folders of the project that would otherwise refer this one.

If it crashed in a class from that project's assembly, you'll be able to specify the source code files since you got the symbols, and since you won't be modifying that project on a regular basis, your VS won't rebuild it every time. You could even unload the project if you want to save some memory, however trivial it might be.